# Why the small entry field for comments on mobiles?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

Since lately, when adding or editing a comment on my mobile phone, the entry field is basically reduced in height.

You can roughly  see two "rows" at a time so you quickly have to start scrolling. Which I find mighty annoying.

Why was that changed? Or is it a bug?

Edit: I am using Chrome on Android, and it looks like this:

[image: screenshot of two lines]

Comment: Maybe it would be a bit clearer if a screenshot was provided

Comment: So, is this a `[discussion]` or a `[bug]` report?

Comment: I see almost 3 full lines on mobile, with Firefox on Android using the responsive design. Are you using the old mobile design or the new responsive one? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Same here with Chrome 67.0.3396.87 on Android 8 (@Stijn, it's the old mobile one).

Comment: @SurajRao Did so.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, if this is an unwanted change of some front end update, I would like to report a bug. If this is on purpose, I would like to discuss that "purpose".

Comment: Considering the fact that different users see different styling, I'd assume it's a bug.

Comment: I see 1 row at a time.....

Comment: Yeah this started happening about a week ago, with only 1-2 lines visible in the comments. But it happens on all SE sites, not just SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus I tend to consider something like this a [tag:feature-request] since [se] seems happy enough to just call a "bug" [tag:status-bydesign] if they don't want to "fix" it.

Comment: I asked this on the SE meta. I only see ~1/2 line in mobile (FF or chrome, samsung s8). Linking since it has a screenshot: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311937/comment-box-only-half-a-line-tall-on-mobile

Answer (score 3):

Please expand the comment field to like 10-15 rows or something.

It is an absolute chore to try and scroll within a compressed textarea on mobile especially when the keyboard fights you for screen real estate after you lift your scroll finger.

Comment: You only get 10 lines for writing posts :/ Everything is a chore